# How to enable extra typographic characters in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 13.10

It was easy to do in Ubuntu 13.04, but I can't understand how to do it in 13.10.

How to enable extra typographic characters in Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 2):

**Keyboard Layout**, now called **Text Entry**, has undergone many changes in the new version of Ubuntu - 13.10 and there is not such a option anymore. At least for now.

Instead, you can use *English (US international with dead keys)* rather than *English (US)*.